# Usar ajax en formulario django, No procesa la peticion POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Tengo un formulario creado en django, al usar ajax no Procesa la petición POST 
uso ***django 1.11.18*** en consola muestra esta error ***"POST /inc/home.html HTTP/1.1" 404 2136*** , Los datos se almacenaran en mysql

**main.js**

```
 var clContactForm = function() {

        /* local validation */
        $('#contactForm').validate({

            /* submit via ajax */
            submitHandler: function(form) {

                var sLoader = $('.submit-loader');

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "inc/home.html",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function() { 

                        sLoader.slideDown("slow");

                    },
                    success: function(msg) {

                        // Message was sent
                        if (msg == 'OK') {
                            sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                            $('.message-warning').fadeOut();
                            $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                            $('.message-success').fadeIn();
                        }
                        // There was an error
                        else {
                            sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                            $('.message-warning').html(msg);
                            $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");
                        }

                    },
                    error: function() {

                        sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                        $('.message-warning').html("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
                        $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");

                    }

                });
            }

        });
    };
```

**template/home.html**

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="" novalidate="novalidate">{% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset>

                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Your Name" value="" minlength="2" required="" aria-required="true"
                                class="full-width">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Your Email" value="" required="" aria-required="true"
                                class="full-width">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject" value="" class="full-width">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <textarea name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" placeholder="Your Message" rows="10" cols="50" required="" aria-required="true"
                                class="full-width"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <button class="full-width btn--primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            <div class="submit-loader">
                                <div class="text-loader">Sending...</div>
                                <div class="s-loader">
                                    <div class="bounce1"></div>
                                    <div class="bounce2"></div>
                                    <div class="bounce3"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Contacto


class FormularioForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Contacto

        fields = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'subject',
            'menssage',
        ]
        labels = {
            'name':'Nombre',
            'email':'Email',
            'subject':'Telefono',
            'mmessage':'Mensaje',
        }
        widgets = {'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),                                              
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'subject': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'message': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Comment: Fijate en la URL de AJAX : url: "inc/home.html",...... esa ruta debe ser la que definas en tus urls.py en otras palabras de ajax mandas hacia un views.py y este procesa los datos recibidos y retorna una respuesta hacia el que la envia en este caso ajax.

Comment: adicional a ello debes enviar tambien por ajax el token de Django

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Es valido quitar el {% csrf_token %} del formulario y que solo acceda por $.ajaxSetup?

Comment: depende como envies la data por ajax puedes hacerla como dices enviar el formulario serializado y ya no necesitas el token por ajax o a su vez enviar el token por ajax